# C# Listview Control equivalent in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an application in android wherein I need to display the items in the list in a manner similar to the Icon View in Windows File Explorer (only the thumbnail and the name is displayed). In C#, I can achieved this through the ListView control. Is there an equivalent component in Android that has the same functionality as a ListView control in C#?

**EDIT**

Here's a link to an image similar to what I want to achieved.

http://goo.gl/vGsgJ

Comment: Android also has ListView.. Have you been thorugh the docs lately..  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, the question is a bit ambiguous. I know there is a ListView in Android, though the functionality is not the same with C#. I believe I wouldn't be able to achieve what I'm trying to do with Android list view since it only allows you to list down items in a vertical list, am I right? sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you mind posting a image example of how you are expecting the result to be, bcoz it might be GridView which you are looking for.

Comment: ah sure, here's an example http://goo.gl/vGsgJ, sorry I'm still not allowed to post an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your image, you're looking for the `GridView` widget:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html

Also, there's a great tutorial on how to load images into a `GridView` on the Android training site:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#gridview